# How can I get SLF4J working on my IntelliJ project?

Tags: java, logging, intellij-idea, slf4j

I'm running the latest IntelliJ with a project that should have a logger. However, I get:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I know there's plugins, and I tried the Log4jMonitor, still got the error. How can I get the logging to actually make the file in the folder it is supposed to w/ IntelliJ? What do I need to download and how do I install it?

Comment: The problem is that you don't have any logging implementation dependency added to the module. What are the dependencies used for logging in this project?

Answer (score 5):

Your project uses slf4j for logging, but no implementation is found at runtime.
You can configure logging by adding eg. log4j (and the slf4j bridge) as follows.

Add the log4j (+slf4j bridge) dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
  </dependency>
```

and add an appropriate `log4j.properties` file under `resources`, with contents eg.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c{36} - %m%n
```

Comment: I usually add `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl` - not sure what the difference is though

Comment: when you say "under `resources`", where would I find that?

Comment: @daniele I'm still getting 'SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details."

Comment: also @boot-and-bonnet, where would I put that?

Comment: @Jerry the resources folder is `${project.basedir}/src/main/resources` . Btw is this project is Maven-based? And, if you still have the "SLF4J: failed to load.." error, double- check that the `slf4j-log4j12` dependency is included in the classpath. In example, can you find the `org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter` class?

Comment: @Daniele this project is maven based; when you say "classpath," do you mean for the entire project? Also, what precisely should be put into the classpath? The entirety of what I might need to put in there? I'm using IntelliJ; how would I do this? I have done what's in your answer so far

Comment: You should add the first snippet I posted (`<..>slf4j-log4j12<..>`) to the project's `pom.xml`. That will include the log4j jar in the classpath of your project. Then, the class `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` should be available; that class comes with the `slf4j-log4j12` jar

Comment: To check if you correctly included the jar; try calling `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton();` from a Java class. Does that compile?

Comment: @Daniele where in the file structure should I find `org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter`?

Comment: you should find it inside a jar file - in the same way as all other classes, eg. `java.lang.Object` (which is in rt.jar). In intellij, you can use the "find class by name" functionality, using ctrl.N.